# Copying data to Blank Cells in column B until the last used range in column A

Tags: excel, vba

I have data that looks like this

[image: Original Data]

and I want to make it look like this

[image]

The code I wrote that goes through all the value in column A and offset the value to column B is

```
Sub FindString()
Dim A As Range, r As Range
Set A = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("A:A"))

For Each r In A
    If IsNumeric(Left(r, 6)) Then
    r.Copy r.Offset(0, 1)
    End If 
Next r  
End Sub
```

this code will copy data from column A to B if first 6 values is numeric, but I want help in copying data to all blank cells in column B until it finds matching value in column A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub FindString()
    Dim A As Range, r As Range, last As Range
    Set A = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("A:A"))

    For Each r In A
        If IsNumeric(Left(r, 6)) Then Set last = r
        If Not last Is Nothing Then last.Copy r.Offset(0, 1)
    Next r
End Sub
```

p.s: beware of the problems when using UsedRange. Consider searching this site for best methods of finding the last non-empty cell in a column.

EDIT

A non VBA method using formula (might be faster)

```
At cell B4: `=A4`
At cell B5: `=IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(A5, 6))),  A5, B4)`
Now copy B5, select the whole column B until last cell and paste.
```

Comment: this works somehow but I am afraid if the data is around 50000 rows this will hangs Excel for a moment

Comment: yes i expect it to be slow. If you have a large amount of data, there are ways to accelerate it, but I think this would deserve another question on its own :)

Comment: I was wondering If there is another way using GOTO  and Selecting  special blank cells in column B then copying the data in cell above (non empty cell) to blank cells

Comment: This might be faster, you can try it. However, for best speed, consider loading all the data into an array at once and working on the array in VBA. Continuously exchanging data between Excel and VBA is generally the major source of slowness.

Comment: You could also try to do it with a formula. I will edit to show my suggestion. It might be faster, but cant tell.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fast method (coincidentally similar to ASH's manual method)

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim r As Range

    With ActiveSheet
        Set r = .Range(.Cells(4, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    End With

    r.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(A4,6))),A4,B3)"
    r.Offset(0, 1) = r.Offset(0, 1).Value

End Sub
```

Runs in <1s for 100,000 rows on my system